# Ubuntu 20.04 multiple monitor issues

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

This issue has only happened recently, before my setup was great.

I was able to have 2 external monitors and have my laptop closed.

Now when I have the monitors connected and working with my docking station if I close the laptop (b/c i just want to use the 2 external monitors)... everything freezes.

I see the mouse on the monitor sometimes but that is it, everything else is black and not responsive.

So I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Displaylink (I am using a docking station).

I deleted the monitor.xml files (this helped a little so that both monitors would connect properly).

From what I have seen my NVIDIA card is "prime". I have tried installing the right drivers but that hasn't made a difference. (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070)

Here is what the logs looks like but i have not been able to make progress with it.

```
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:53 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
10:41:45 kernel: overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
10:41:45 kernel: aufs aufs_fill_super:918:mount[1962]: no arg
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 kernel: evdi: [E] evdi_painter_connect:856 Edid length too small
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: Failed to create interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: -22 (Invalid argument)
10:41:43 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: kernel reports: Attribute failed policy validation
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
10:41:40 kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
10:41:40 kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
10:41:39 kernel: 
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
10:41:39 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The issue seems to be with the newer kernel, booting with the older kernel resolves the issue for me. You can change the grub default to force booting with kernel 5.8.0:

```
- in /etc/default/grub change GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2" 
- sudo update-grub
- reboot
```

Some more people with the same issue: https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67821

---

Confirming I'm having the exact same issue since yesterday, using ThinkPad docking station with DisplayLink drivers and NVidia graphics card. Reinstalling drivers did not help. Also tried the solution outlined here but that caused my system not to boot my X server anymore: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1859356-x-server-crashes-on-nvidia-systems-when-displaylin

Comment: ok this helped but now i am in a login loop

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues connecting my ubuntu 20.04 lenovo T490 with my second Dell monitor. Error message was "No DP signal from your device". It suddenly started failing, I reinstalled but still had issues. This fixed the issue for me.

```
    - in /etc/default/grub change GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
- sudo update-grub
- reboot laptop
```

Comment: ok this helped but now i am in a login loop