# Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13 does not work with my laptop display

Tags: kernel, display

If I do "lock" and return the screen of my lap monitor is only random dots of all colour. Please notice that if I use other displays with USB display link these monitors works correctly, but the laptop gets VERY slow.

It behaves the same if i try to change display resolution! I lose the laptop display with random dots of color. If I do "suspend" the laptop seem to be in deadlock and black.

I followed the recommendation on a similar question;
[Ubuntu 20.04 multiple monitor issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356950/ubuntu-20-04-multiple-monitor-issues?newreg=aecff39b47b94d0f8cedfd7771bb0363)

And revert from kernel 5.13 to kernel 5.11. and now everything works fine without problem.

Any ideas what to do to adjust my laptop to new kernels?

I could also see similarity to
[Ubuntu 20.04.3 hangs on boot after upgrade to 5.13 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388449/ubuntu-20-04-3-hangs-on-boot-after-upgrade-to-5-13-kernel)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is happening.

Check the solution here (it worked for me):
[Ubuntu boots to flickering screen with white noise on primary monitor but only with specific Linux kernels - advice on how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388054/ubuntu-boots-to-flickering-screen-with-white-noise-on-primary-monitor-but-only-w?newreg=795dda8bdb734b00a0fdd93f3e4e7f4e)

> I had the same problem and the solution to use switchblade graphics mode is to go back to kernel `5.11.0.46` (somehow). If you have a BIOS switch for it, you can select discrete graphics mode. Also, maybe try to connect your laptop with an external monitor.